# Macintosh SE/30 cover screw size

Tags: apple-macintosh, maintenance

I lost the 4 Torq (T15) screws that hold together the case for a Mac SE/30.

Does anyone know the size and the groove spacing to order a compatible one?

I found these on eBay, but I'm not sure about the winding spacing, [(x10pcs) M5 x 25mm, Black, Button, Torx, Socket, Screw, ~ 10.9, T15, 5mm](https://www.ebay.com/itm/x10pcs-M5-x-25mm-Black-Button-Torx-Socket-Screw-10-9-T15-5mm/191513852242).

Answer (score 7):

The rear case cover screws are part number 426-1007 for the top two screws ("Screw, Tap, M 4.22 x 1.41 x 16, Torx, Zinc") and 435-5002 for the bottom two ("Screw, Tap, 8-32 x .625, Torx, Blk Zinc Oxide"), per [SE/30 exploded diagram](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/legacy/macintosh_se.30.pdf#page=89)
 and [parts list entries](https://vintageapple.org/macbooks/pdf/Service_Guide_Macintosh_Computers_March_1991.pdf#page=36).  An #8-32 is a standard diameter and thread spacing of screw that is common in computer case screws, but I can't parse that description of the other one.

Comment: "M 4.22 x 1.41 x 16" looks like the notation for a metric screw thread of 4.22mm outer diameter, 1.41mm pitch, 16mm long -- but that's very much not a standard metric thread.  It might be a metric description of a #8-18 UTS screw, but that's *also* very much not a standard size.

Comment: English-standard wood screws #8 or #6 have about the right diameter, the first specification isn't for a machine-screw thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be as original as possible, you can use any two M4-sized (Metric) screws for the lower two holes and search a box of assorted self-tapping screws by probing the holes of the front cover without back for proper fitting.